# Why jQuery doesn't find an element in ready event?

Tags: jquery, properties, ready

I defined object of *CgridAdminView* with the properties and methods:

```
var CgridAdminView = {
    controller_name: 'work',
    div_table_id: 'grid-admin-works',
    tr_add: $('#' + this.div_table_id).find('tr').eq(1),
    disabled: '.td_workGroup',
    list_cols: [
        'index',
        'shortName',
        'fullName',
        'codeName',
        'workGroup_id',
        'period',
        'performers']
};
```

*tr_add* property doesn't contain elements in the processor of an event of *ready*:

```
$(function(){
    CgridAdminView.tr_add.hide();
});
```

It is works:

```
$(function(){
     var tr_add = $('#'+CgridAdminView.div_table_id).find('tr').eq(1);
     tr_add.hide();
});
```

But *tr_add* property contains the necessary element in methods of object of *CgridAdminView*.

In what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not declaring `CgridAdminView` inside a dom ready handler

```
$(function () {

    var CgridAdminView = {
        controller_name: 'work',
        div_table_id: 'grid-admin-works',
        tr_add: $('#' + this.div_table_id).find('tr').eq(1),
        disabled: '.td_workGroup',
        list_cols: [
            'index',
            'shortName',
            'fullName',
            'codeName',
            'workGroup_id',
            'period',
            'performers']
    };
    CgridAdminView.tr_add.hide();
})
```

Because the `tr_add` properties value is assigned when `CgridAdminView` is created, so when the object is create if the target element is not loaded then the evaluation of `$('#' + this.div_table_id).find('tr').eq(1)` will not return any result.

The main point is the jQuery selector need to happen in dom ready